# Objects rotate strangely when entire mesh is rotated

Tags: mesh, parent, origin

When I rotate my model, or even part of the model, each object in the mesh rotates by itself.
It's like each object has it's own origin (even in the same part of mesh)
I tried setting object's parents, but that didn't work. I tried applying all modifiers, that didn't change anything. I tried changing all of the objects' origin point to 0,0,0. And that didn't work either. This still persists after joining all of the meshes together. Can anyone help?
[image: Full mesh (all joined together)]
[image: Example of deformed rotation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the pivot center of rotation to be Median point as shown below:

[image]